# Emulating mailer delegation functionality on linux

Tags: email, dovecot, exim

We need to set up a linux based mailing infrastructure, that has similar capabilities as Exchange Server has (other collaboration tools are not needed).
As far as I could reach Exim4 + Dovecot seem to be the proper direction, but we could not find any clear advice on how to set up the delegation and shared mailboxes (without providing credentials to the person who gets the delegated right).

- Dovecot supports LDAP authentication
- Dovecot supports virtual mailboxes
- Dovecot supports IMAP ACLs, granting access to other mailboxes can be achieved
- Exim supports dovecot as the authenticator
- *But how can we set up Exim to support sending mails "on behalf of"? What we would like to achieve is that a user having full access to an other mailbox than his own should be able to send mails in the name of that specific other recipient without the need to know the password of that other account. Of course, this should be allowed under these strict circumstances and nobody else should be able to send in in any other's name.*

Of course, we are open to suggestions for other tools providing the same or better features. Thank you.

Comment: Nobody ever wanted such thing? Strange...

Answer (score 0):

Exchange is a bit weird in the way it locks down the From header and offers UI to manage permissions around this. Most smtp servers leave this to the MUA which range from being highly inflexible (such as webmail applications which only offer a single address) to complete freedom (the From setting is freeform text on each email you send). Exim offers a few controls around this server side with the so called "submission mode" documented in http://exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-message_processing.html. If you add the control = submission then a Sender: header will be added if the From: header doesn't match the envelope and you can lock this down to specific authenticated users.